# Density of states of a finite potential well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, density-of-states

Considering a finite square potential well.

The solution of it gives the isolated bound states (below zero) and continuous scattering states  (above zero). Here the isolated and continuous are the energy eigenvalues.

Then my question comes, if we consider the density of states of the electrons for the potential well, when the $E>0$, it seems the density of states will be infinite. I think
there must be something wrong, but I can not tell.

[image]

Comment: **[...] we consider the density of states of the electrons for the potential well, when the $E>0$, it seems the density of states will be infinite. "* What makes you think that? Certainly for such a well with just one electron the number of energy eigenvalues is finite. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/pfbox.html

Comment: He probably thinks the density of states is infinite because the states are continuous rather than discrete. But, just like for a free particle, we can use a standard trick to make the states countable and then we can make sense of the density of states (and then take the continuum limit). The trick is to put the system in a large box and this makes the continuum states become discrete. This makes it easier to see that the density of states is finite. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model#Density_of_states

Comment: This makes sense since, because the energy of the continuum states is continuous, you have a continuous function $g_c(E)\propto \sqrt{E}$ as the density of states that you can integrate again $dE$ to count states. OTOH, the discrete states will have density of states that looks like $g_d(E)=\sum_i \delta(E - E_i)$.

Comment: Finally, the number of states in a volume $V$ is counted by considering $N = V\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi \hbar)^3}$, which is infinite for an infinite volume $V$. Similarly, it is infinite as $\hbar\to 0$, so I don't think OP's confusion about infinite states (and/or  density of states) in the continuum is unfounded. It's a reasonable question to have.